# How do you solve the equation $5e^4 = \log 3^t$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How do you solve the equation $5e^4= \log 3^t$?

Comment: This is not trigonometry...

Comment: do you mean $5 e^4 = \log (3^t)$ ? If so , is the base of the log $10$ or $e$ ?

Comment: Irrelevant either way @WW1 as we can express $t$ in terms of whatever base logarithm it was in the first place.  @ Moh, remember that $\log (a^b) = b\log(a)$.  This implies that $\log(3^t) = t\log(3)$.  Continue from there.

Answer (score 2):

$$\log3^t=5e^4\implies t\log3=5e^4=\implies t=\frac{5e^4}{\log3}$$